# Ошибка error C2512: arrayob<type>: нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++, наследование

Написал код программы. Но выдает данную ошибку. Помогите исправить.
Только другое ничего не меняйте, код выполнен по заданию, но во многих местах конечно можно было сделать проще!
Код:

````
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <class type> // объявление шаблона класса
class arrayob // класс Динамический массив
{
public:
    type **contents; // массив указателей на объекты типа type
    int size; // максимальное количество объектов в массиве
    int n; // реальное количество объектов в массиве
    arrayob(int number)
    {
        contents = new type *[size = number];
    }
    ~arrayob();
    void add(type *p)
    {
        if (n == size)cerr << "Выход за пределы";
        else { contents[n] = p; n++; }
    }
    void del(int pos) {
        if (n <= pos)
            return;
        for (int i = pos; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            contents[i] = contents[i + 1];
        }
        --n;
    }
    type & operator [] (int x) // итератор массива объектов
    {
        if ((x < 0) || (x >= size))
        {
            cerr << "Ошибочный индекс " << x << endl; x = 0;
        }
        return *contents[x];
    }
    int sizeofmas() { return n; } // реальный размер массива
};
template <class type>
class sor : public arrayob<type> {
public:
    using arrayob<type>::contents;
    using arrayob<type>::size;
    using arrayob<type>::n;
    using arrayob<type>::add;
    using arrayob<type>::del;
    using arrayob<type>::sizeofmas;
    sor(int number)
    {
        contents = new type *[size = number];
    }
    ~sor();
    void sortirovka() {
        int i, j;
        type *tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) // i - номер прохода
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) // внутренний цикл прохода
            {
                if (contents[j + 1] < contents[j])
                {
                    tmp = contents[j + 1];
                    contents[j + 1] = contents[j];
                    contents[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

template <class type> arrayob<type>::~arrayob()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) delete contents[i];
    delete[]contents;
}
class TNum // класс Число
{
public: int num;
        virtual void Print(void) { cout << num << " "; }
        TNum() { cout << "Введите число" << endl; cin >> num; }
        TNum(int n) :num(n) {}
        virtual ~TNum(void) {}
};
class TStr :public TNum // класс Строка
{
public: char *st;
        virtual void Print(void) { 
            //TNum::Print();
            cout << st << " ";
        }
        TStr(); // конструктор по умолчанию
        TStr(char *s) :TNum(strlen(s))// конструктор с параметрами
        {
            st = new char[num + 1]; strcpy(st, s);
            st[num] = '\0';
        }
            virtual ~TStr(void) { delete[] st; }
};
TStr::TStr() :TNum(40)
{
    cout << "Введите строку " << endl;
    st = new char[num + 1]; cin >> st;
    num = strlen(st); st[num + 1] = '\0';
}

sor<TNum> ob_a(5); //массив из 5 указателей на объекты

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "russian");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            ob_a.add(new TStr);
    cout << "Содержимое контейнера " << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i < ob_a.sizeofmas(); i++)
        ob_a[i].Print();
    cout << "\n";
    ob_a.del(0);
    cout << "Содержимое контейнера " << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i < ob_a.sizeofmas(); i++)
        ob_a[i].Print();
    ob_a.sortirovka();
    cout << "Содержимое контейнера " << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i < ob_a.sizeofmas(); i++)
        ob_a[i].Print();
    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

Эта (одна из нескольких) ваша конкретная ошибка состоит в том, что в

```
sor(int number)
{
    contents = new type *[size = number];
}
```

не указан конструктор родительского типа. Поэтому должен использоваться конструктор по умолчанию, генерируемый компилятором, для `arrayob<type>`. Но он не генерируется, потому что вы определили свои пользовательские конструкторы.

Поскольку вообще непонятно, зачем вы пытаетесь выделять память в конструкторе `sor`, если это же действие выполняется в предке, проще всего заменить конструктор на

```
sor(int number):arrayob<type>(number) {}
```

убрав ненужное дублирование.

И еще раз: это не единственная неприятность в вашем коде. Но вы четко попросили ничего больше не менять:

> Помогите исправить. Только другое ничего не меняйте

Так сказать, подчиняюсь...

Comment: Зачем так отвечать? Я имел в виду глобально ничего не менять, основные конструкции! Смысл помогать, если исправив эту ошибку я встречу другую. Помогите тогда уже до конца исправить.

Comment: Просто, когда я задаю вопросы на подобных форумах, я часто встречаю людей, которые говорят менять весь код, но при этом никаких дельных советов не дают, а я должен выполнять всё заново сам и ловить новые ошибки. Либо меня просят поменять то, что я не могу поменять по заданию.

Comment: Я не решаю задачи для себя, а решаю по конкретной программе, и я не могу писать так как вздумается. Поэтому и написал такое уточнение.

Comment: Чтобы исправить "до конца", надо как минимум знать, что программа должна делать :) Ну вот один из примеров: `cin >> st;`, где `st` — `char*`. В современном С++ это уже запрещено, как и, например, `gets()`. Или отсутствующий деструктор `sor`. Но делать за вас все — это подпортить вам же возможность учиться. Так что пробуйте вылавливать свои ошибки самостоятельно.

Comment: Ну спасибо блин >:(

Comment: Сидеть часами над парой строчек наверное будет полезным времяпреповождением...

Comment: Это — **очень** полезное времяпровождение. Если не просто сидеть, а *думать*. И если, конечно, вы хотите научиться программировать, а не стать [гугл-программистом](https://habr.com/ru/post/521104/), который хорошо умеет даже не решения в Интернете искать, а выцыганивать их у других...